# VBA - getting sub or function not defined error with error handling active

Tags: vba, error-handling

I've got a mystery. In a project I made a while back, there is a check when you activate a different sheet ("Worksheet_Activate" event). The check is to see if there is anything in the "UnsaVedList()" string array, meaning there are unsaved changes. That variable is redimmed early on, but I suppose it's possible somehow that it can disappear and no longer be dimensioned - I don't get that part, but that's not even the issue here.

The issue is that when at least one user's computer hits this line of code where it checks the first bank of that variable, the user is getting an error breaking the code because the variable is not defined. That is only 2 lines after an "On Error GoTo label" line, which is still active at the time of the error popup.

Any idea how this could happen or how to fix it? I'll post the whole sub below

[image: Error image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim dontSave As Integer, unsavedDay As Date, backSheet As Worksheet
Set backSheet = ActiveSheet
On Error GoTo noUnsaved
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not UnsaVedList(0) = Empty Then
        unsavedDay = DateSerial(Int(Left(UnsaVedList(0), 4)),Int(Mid(UnsaVedList(0), 5, 2)), Int(Mid(UnsaVedList(0), 7, 2)))
        Sheets(18 - DateDiff("d", unsavedDay, Sheets(5).Cells(2, 1).Value)).Activate
        dontSave = MsgBox("You have unsaved changes on " & Format(unsavedDay, "ddd d mmm") & ". Click Yes to review the changes or No to abandon the changes on this day", vbYesNo, "Review changes?")
        Select Case dontSave
            Case 6 'yes
                dontSave = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Int(Right(UnsaVedList(0), 2)), After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
                ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(dontSave, 3), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells(dontSave, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 14)).Select
            Case 7 'no
                ReDim UnsaVedList(0)
                backSheet.Activate
        End Select
    End If
noUnsaved: '''<< this is where it's supposed to jump to!
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: In the VB editor go to Tools >> Options >> General and under "Error Trapping" make sure it's not set to "break on all errors". If that's set then any error handling is ignored and your code will halt on all errors.

Comment: That's a very good thought. Is that client specific, or would it go with the project? Because mine's set to only show unhandled, and I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: @dya I assume that variable is declared as public in a module (normally you'd get a subscript out of range error if the array wasn't dimensioned, in this case the compiler does not actually recognize the variable declaration) and there's no chance the user could select the worksheet before that variable is assigned?

Comment: That setting only explains why the error handler isn't working for the other user.  That's not the "out of the box" configuration though, so it must have been changed at some point. It's not a per-project setting.

Comment: @Absinthe The variable is declared publicly in a module, along with a small selection of other variables. It gets dimensioned through a sub called on workbook open event, and also on the sub that makes all the sheets in that book visible, otherwise the user can only see the blank cover sheet with a button.

Comment: Try putting a Stop (https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/stop-statement.htm) in your workbook open event, then step through (https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/step-through-code.htm) and watch  (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/watch_window2013.php) the variable

Comment: Good idea, but I've fully debugged it with watches on my computer and it works fine. There just seems to be something wrong with the other computer. But dropping a variable after minutes or hours is something I've come to learn the need to handle. And as @TimWilliams mentioned, my ultimate issue is that even the error handling isn't working.

Comment: I'll get a chance to remote into the user's computer to check their error handling radio buttons on Monday, hopefully will have success there.

Comment: Well, I got a look at her settings, and it all appears normal. I'm just going to recommend that she have Office wiped and reinstalled.